# Showing all deprecated warnings in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, deprecated, deprecation-warning

How do I show all deprecated warnings in Xcode for my iOS app?

Clicking on the `Issue Navigator > Buildtime >` then scrolling down to `Deprecations` only seems to show deprecations for opened or previously-opened files. When I open more files, more deprecations appear. I'd like to see a complete view of all deprecated methods across all files.

Comment: Create a build normally shows all of it.

Comment: @GeneCode I have done a normal Build, even Clean beforehand, but still I only get deprecated warnings for current files

Comment: try `Product > Analyze`

Comment: Select Your Project Files -> General -> Deployment Target -> select latest os so it will show all methods which is deprecated according to iOS version

Answer (score 2):

According to an [answer in Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81429), which I myself have verified.

> If your Deployment target is older than the version of iOS that the
>   API was deprected in (so if your deployment targer is iOS 8.0 or
>   lower), the compiler won't give you deprecation warnings for that API.

So, do what [this user answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287505/ravi-panchal), and select latest OS version is available in Project Files -> General -> Deployment Target

Answer (score 2):

As many of you worked with issue navigator but do not aware where it exactly and how you can find the deprecated methods so let me show you by screenshot

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Issue Navigator.
In the Issue navigator, type "deprecated" in the below filter. 
Now you will be able to see all (and only) deprecated Buildtime warnings.